# How to seed image file in nested attributes Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error when trying to seed database with image file in nested attributes.

```
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0; required keywords: io, filename)
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :founders, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :founders, allow_destroy: true
```

founder.rb

```
class Founder < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, optional: true
  has_one_attached :profile_picture
end
```

seed.rb

```
user = User.create!(email: 'user@example.com', password: '1234567890')
10.times do |index|
  @product = Product.create(
    user: user,
    name: "Product #{index+1}",
    tagline: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    industry: Faker::Company.industry,
    website: Faker::Internet.url,
    company_name: Faker::Company.name,
    company_website: Faker::Internet.url,
    founders_attributes: [
      {
        name: Faker::Name.name,
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        website: Faker::Internet.url,
        profile_picture: { io: File.open(Rails.root + "app/assets/images/profile_picture.png"), filename: 'profile_picture.png', content_type: 'image/png' }
      },
      {
        name: Faker::Name.name,
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        website: Faker::Internet.url,
        profile_picture: { io: File.open(Rails.root + "app/assets/images/profile_picture.png"), filename: 'profile_picture.png', content_type: 'image/png' }
      }
    ]
  )
end
```

I have no idea to solve this error.
Give me some advice please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it without nested attributes. And by the way you didn't close your files:

```
PNG_PATH = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'images', 'profile_picture.png')

user = User.create!(email: 'user@example.com', password: '1234567890')
1.upto(10) do |index|
  @product = Product.create(
    user: user,
    name: "Product #{index}",
    tagline: Faker::Lorem.sentence,
    industry: Faker::Company.industry,
    website: Faker::Internet.url,
    company_name: Faker::Company.name,
    company_website: Faker::Internet.url
  )

  2.times do
    founder =
      @product.founders.create(
        name: Faker::Name.name,
        email: Faker::Internet.email,
        website: Faker::Internet.url
      )

    File.open(PNG_PATH) do |file|
      founder.profile_picture.attach(io: file, filename: File.basename(file.to_path))
    end
  end
end
```